# In cosmology, what do you call a visual representation of fundamental elements/forces in the universe?

Tags: terminology, cosmology, term

I am interested in learning about various cosmological systems that come from various philosophies and religion throughout history. To understand what I really mean, here's a graphical example:

[image]

I am interested in such system, because some cosmological views didn't include metal, some would also include things like wind or air, and more abstract things like death. Is there a word for this, so I can easily continue research?

Comment: Elements.......

Comment: You may search kabbalastic sephirot model which is very similar to above semantic network path diagram…